# I calculated internal energy at various temperatures and pressures. My results differ from someone else's. Is this OK?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, molecular-dynamics

I would like to make sure that my understanding of internal energy is correct.  I'm not a thermodynamicist, so apologies in advance for what is probably a basic question.

I previously calculated density for a liquid system via molecular dynamics (NPT ensemble).  I needed the results for use in fluid flow simulations.  The calculations also generated internal energy, which I have so far ignored.  However, someone has expressed interest in comparing my internal energy results with his.  He looked at the same system, but used a different calculation method.

His internal energies, E, for all temperatures and pressures are between -11000 to -12000 kJ/mol.  Mine are between -38000 and -40000 kJ/mol.

Here's my question.  **Is it correct that I don't need to worry that one of us has made a mistake--that it's OK for the absolute values to differ as long as the differences are consistent?**  For example, his highest-temperature, highest-pressure data point differs from his lowest-temperature, lowest-pressure data point by about the same amount as mine does.

Comment: Generally, absolute energies aren't meaningful and we are mainly interested in energy differences. The concern I would have in comparing your results is that yours seem to have a much larger range (2000 vs 1000).

Comment: @Tyberius, thanks very much for helping with such a basic question.  If you want to put that in an answer, I will mark it correct.

Comment: You may want to post this question at the material modeling SE site instead (I think Tyberius for one is a regular there).

Comment: @BuckThorn, thanks.  I'll do that if I haven't heard back from him by tomorrow--don't want him to think I deleted his current effort in case he checks back today!